# In OLSR instead of MS if MPR selector are used, will it work?

Tags: routing, protocol-theory, mobile, ad-hoc-wireless, olsr

In  the TC  message of  OLSR    that    is  created by  each    node    x,  x   includes    its MS  set,
i.e.,   a   list    of  nodes   that    have    selected    it  as  an  MPR.    Assume  instead that    TC  messages
created by  each    node    x,  let x   include its MPR set (rather than    its MS  set).   Will    the 
routing still   work    properly?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: Just a glossary: **OLSR** is Optimised Link State Routing Protocol; **TC** is topology control, a type of routing message in OLSR; **MPR** is multipoint relay, a node which retransmits link state information **MS** is multipoint relay selector, ie a node which has chosen a given MPR, "set" has the meaning of "unordered collection".

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to answer your question because there are some assumptions wrong in it.

First, in OLSR not all nodes generate TC messages.  Only nodes that have been selected as a MPR generate and relay TCs.

Second, the node generating the TC message includes in it the list of all its symmetric neighbors, not just those that have selected it as a MPR (i.e. its MS set).

Here's [a short explanation of the OLSR protocol](http://www.crans.org/~raffo/papers/phdthesis/thesisch1.html#x5-210001.4.4) and the [RFC (3626) that details it](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3626.txt).